# Kendo Datepicker disturbing the alignment

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, datepicker, telerik

I have started using **Telerik kendo datepicker** along with **AngularJS** in my UI builtwith **Bootstrap**. After deploying the application (using **Visual Studio**) to the server ,all the bootstrap Containers are left aligned .I also have few **Bootstrap accordions** in UI.

When I click on accordion , then only UI takes the desired alignment.(desired alignment is container coming middle in the screen)

Why is it so?

> Bootstrap Version: Bootstrap v3.0.0
>
> AngularJS Version: AngularJS v1.3.5
>
> Kendo UI Version : Kendo UI v2015.1.429

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140070/bootstrap-3-grid-system-does-not-work-correctly-within-a-3rd-party-styled-div-k/31140422#31140422

Comment: I tried this ,but it is not helpful (may be because issue is coming in the deployed code).