# Bootstrap form in kendo ui modal / popup window

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, popupwindow, grid-system

is possible use bootstrap form in modal window of kendo ui? I need form with inputs in many columns. I've tried to use default bootstrap like in ordinary html file but that's not work correctly. Thanks

Comment: I don't see any problems why it wouldn't work

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140070/bootstrap-3-grid-system-does-not-work-correctly-within-a-3rd-party-styled-div-k/31140422#31140422